# Trying to upload a file from C++ with CURL to PHP

Tags: php, c++, curl

I'm trying to upload a picture (and its thumb) with CURL from C++ to my server.

The C++ doesn't present a problem by the moment, but the point is the following:

Immagine this is my code in PHP:

```
<?php
    $valid = $_GET['valid'];
    echo "hola";
    file_put_contents('queries.txt', "eh!\n");
?>
```

when I call my `file.php` it has to write a "queries.txt" in the same folder (and it does it).

Now, when calling if from C++, this is the code:

```
    string url = "http://myserver.com/file.php";

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    // set target url
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // holders
    struct curl_httppost* beginPostList = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost* endPostList = NULL;

    string concat1 = tempFolder + imageName;
    string concat2 = tempFolder + image200Name;

    curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image",
                 CURLFORM_FILE, &concat1, CURLFORM_END);
    curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "thumb",
                 CURLFORM_FILE, &concat2, CURLFORM_END);

    // perform
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, beginPostList);
    CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

My current error is that the server isn't being called (because no "queries.txt" is being created), but if I remove this lines:

```
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image",
             CURLFORM_FILE, &concat1, CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "thumb",
             CURLFORM_FILE, &image200Name, CURLFORM_END);
```

the PHP script gets called perfectly. So, why CURL is not calling my script when adding any file?

Thank you in advance.

---

Edit:

1.- I've tried to call it by setting the content type:

```
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image",
             CURLFORM_FILE, &concat1,
             CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "image/jpeg", CURLFORM_END);
```

but nothing happened

---

POSSIBLE ERROR:

I'm trying to not setting anything and I'm getting HTTP STATUS = 200, but if I set any file to upload, I get **HTTP STATUS = 0**... why?

Comment: How big are these files? Possibly you have exceeded the max_upload_filesize.

Comment: 52 KB, not really big, it's set to 20 MB ish

Comment: Shouldn't be `concat2` on your second `curl_formadd`, instead of `image200Name` ?

Comment: @1nflktd yes, you're right, but anyway it's happening with any file. I'm going to edit it. Thanks to note it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a *c++ string* when it expects a *c string*

Try:

```
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image",
             CURLFORM_FILE, concat1.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
curl_formadd(&beginPostList, &endPostList, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "thumb",
             CURLFORM_FILE, concat2.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
```

Comment: When I received your answer I changed that before seeing the answer... and YES!!!! Thank you very much :)